# Why is the left number inclusive and the right number exclusive when using the colon operator in Python arrays/strings?

Tags: python, slice

I was just confused why in the following example the number on the left is included, while the number on the right isn't:

```py
a = "0123456789"
a[:]  # "0123456789"
a[1:]  # "123456789" -> includes the 1
# and this confuses me:
a[:5]  # "01234" -> excludes the 5
a[1:5]  # "1234" -> again
```

Can anybody explain why it is designed this way?

Comment: Python as other programming languages start counting from zero, therefore 4 is the 5th and last element from left.

Comment: A nice explanation, [why](https://skillcrush.com/blog/why-programmers-start-counting-at-zero/)

Comment: If it helps, the colon isn't an operator, it's just part of the slicing syntax. You can find a list of operators under [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are slicing a string!

A slice operation starts with index 0

In python a slice operation is of format [start:stop:step]

```
Keep a example string as MyString = "Hi MoPaMo"
Here the first letter has the index as 0
Hi MoPaMo
012345678

So print(MyString[0:4]) is going to output the 1st 4 index numbers
Hi M
0123
From Index 0 to index 4

a="0123456789"
So in a[:]       you are telling there is no start or stop, print everything
In print(a[1:])  you are telling start from index 1
In print(a[:5])  you are telling stop at index 5, therefore it prints 01234
In print(a[1:5]) you are telling to start at index 1 and stop at index 5 which results in 1234

print(a[1:8:2]) is going to print 1357
Here you are telling to skip alternate elements
```

Do check out this doc [Pythons String Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: Especially relevant from the tutorial is the bit from "Note how the start is always included, and the end always excluded." up to (but not including :-P) "For non-negative indices"